# Erosion and dilation of binary image

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-morphology

Say I erode and then dilate a binary image contains single object with the same structuring element (i.e. that is opening).

Why I don't get the original object back?

Comment: If you are doing image-processing in a programming language, you may want to add its tag.

Answer (score 1):

In an erosion, you loose information. There are multiple regions with different boundaries that result in the same thing when eroded.

As an example, see this doc entry: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html
The face and neck became completely black.

In a binary image, there may be elements which are smaller than the structuring element. There are completely eroded away.

The opening operation is documented here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html

Comment: The links are broken.

Comment: Think of an image made of isolated pixels. Erosion will delete them. Recovery is impossible.